# Why does while loop statment doesn't work the way i want?

Tags: python-3.x

```
player = input('do you wanna play the game').lower()

while player != 'yes' or 'no':

    player = input('say yes or no')

if player == 'yes':
   print('ok')
else:
    quit()
```

in this code even when we type yes or no it doesn't respond to it and just continues the while loop i don't know what is wrong

I was expecting to when the user enters yes or no just jump to the if else statment otherwise just stuck in loop

Comment: `player != 'yes' or 'no'` will always be true

Comment: `If` is not valid Python syntax. Are you just typing code in the question without checking whether it parses?

Comment: "or" is going to return one or the other. `player != 'yes'` if that evaluates to false, then `'no'` is returned. It's not clear how you want them to evaluate though. Maybe you want something like `while player not in ["yes", "no"]:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
player = ''
print('do you want to play the game')
while player != 'yes' and player != 'no':
    player = input('say yes or no ').lower()

if player == 'yes':
   print('ok')
else:
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is in the while loop condition. The condition `player != 'yes' or 'no'` is not being evaluated as you expect. It is actually being evaluated as `(player != 'yes') or ('no')`. Since 'no' is a non-empty string, it is considered truthy, and the condition will always be true.

To fix this issue, you should change the condition to:

```py
    while player != 'yes' and player != 'no':
```

Here's the corrected code:

```py
    player = input('do you wanna play the game').lower()
    
    while player != 'yes' and player != 'no':
        player = input('say yes or no')
    
    if player == 'yes':
        print('ok')
    else:
        quit()
```

Now, the while loop will continue until the user inputs either 'yes' or 'no', and then it will proceed to the if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of the `while` is incorrect, you can pick any from the following for the intended usage:

```py
for player in ["yes", "no", "other"]:
    print()
    print(f"{player=}")
    print(f"{player != 'yes' and player != 'no'      = }")
    print(f"{not (player == 'yes' or player == 'no') = }")
    print(f"{player not in ['yes', 'no']             = }")
    print(f"{not player in ['yes', 'no']             = }")
```

which prints:

```py
player='yes'
player != 'yes' and player != 'no'      = False
not (player == 'yes' or player == 'no') = False
player not in ['yes', 'no']             = False
not player in ['yes', 'no']             = False

player='no'
player != 'yes' and player != 'no'      = False
not (player == 'yes' or player == 'no') = False
player not in ['yes', 'no']             = False
not player in ['yes', 'no']             = False

player='other'
player != 'yes' and player != 'no'      = True
not (player == 'yes' or player == 'no') = True
player not in ['yes', 'no']             = True
not player in ['yes', 'no']             = True
```